# Prism composite application - Blendability

Tags: silverlight-4.0, prism, ninject, prism-4

We are using Prism and is an excellent framework for composition and modularity. However, I haven't seen a good story around Blendability with Prism composition. When you have a code that has Regions, how do you generally support blendability with it?

I saw an [interesting blog post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2011/01/03/blendability-part-ii-design-time-support-for-prism.aspx) which takes an approach of creating  design time bootstrapper, module catalog, container to support this.

What is your experience with this? Is PnP team coming up with a better story around it? (ie maybe embed design time bootstrapper, designer time region managers inside Prism)?

I am trying to get this working for a modular Silverlight application using Ninject. I can try to follow above link and make it work, but I wanted to see if someone has better ideas around it?

Answer (score 0):

The series you provided in your link is very thorough (especially if you're using MEF (parts 3 and 4)). I'd stick with that to get the blendability you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

These 2 links are useful for ur purpose:

http://blogs.southworks.net/gmaliandi/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921098%28PandP.40%29.aspx